# Chrome dev tools: Search across all scripts doesn't find everything

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I sometimes notice that the `search all` (Ctrl+Shift+F) function in the chrome dev tools doesn't actually seem to find everything.

I'm using ExtJS in my main application and when I search for something which is definitely within the libraries sources and already loaded I sometimes notice that for one thing subsequent searches provide different results and for another thing not everything is found:

[image]

On the screenshot I have been searching for `headerCt` which occurs in the currently open file `Table.js` but neither of the 8 occurrence within this file shows up in the search result.

Is this a bug in the dev tools or am I missing something here?

Ps.: I'm currently running version 40.0.2214 but I've also recognized this in some older versions.

Comment: I'm running version 56 and still have this problem :(